# How to read a config from storage to provide url for DataProvider inside react-admin

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-admin

I added [react admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/) in a sample project, in dataProvider I use [simpleRestProvider](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-simple-rest), that is initialized with httpClient and apiHost, and everithing works as expected, but I want to take apiHost from config file that is fetched in index and is set into the store

index.tsx

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('content'),
    () => config
            .fetchConfig()//after fetch is saved in store
            .catch(console.error('error', '[App]'))
);
```

App.tsx

```
 <Admin
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        authProvider={authProvider}
        dashboard={Dashboard}
         ....
</Admin>
```

dataProvider.ts

```
//const apiHost = "https://example.com"
const apiHost = store.getState().config.apiHost;

const httpClient = async (url, options = {}) => {
...
return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
};

const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider(apiHost, httpClient);
export default dataProvider;
```

on init `store.getState().config.apiHost` return error because config is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument of `ReactDom.render()` executes *after* the component is mounted ([source](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render)). That's the problem: you first render the app (and initialize the dataProvider), then set the configuration.

To set the contiguration earlier, you'll have to create a wrapper component around the react-admin App that fetches your config, and only mounts the App after the config is received.

Something like:

```
const AppWrapper = () => {
   const [configFetched, setConfigFetched] = useState(false); 
   useEffect(() => {
      config
         .fetchConfig()//after fetch is saved in store
         .then(() => setConfigFetched(true))
         .catch(console.error('error', '[App]'));
    }, []);
    return configFetched ? <App /> : null;
}
```

Comment: May be: return configFetched ? <App /> : null;

Comment: You're right Max, I updated the example.